# In application addition of new tkinter modules and the ability to call on the entries from them

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

The following is in reference to a python3 tkinter GUI as an interface for a mySQL database.

I'd like to know if it's possible to add additional labels and entries inside the application via a button.

The below is my code:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None,x=None):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.master = master
    self.pack()
    self.create_widgets()
    self.xy=x
def create_widgets(self):
    self.label1=tk.Label(self, text="Athlete")
    self.label1.grid(row=2)
    self.Athlete=tk.Entry(self)
    self.Athlete.grid(row=2, column=1)
    self.button1=tk.Button(self,text='Commit')
    self.button1['command']=self.Commit
    self.button1.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2)
    self.label2=tk.Label(self,text="Program")
    self.label2.grid(row=4,column=5)
    self.Exercise=tk.Label(self,text="Exercise")
    self.Exercise.grid(row=5,column=2)
    self.Weight=tk.Label(self,text="Weight")
    self.Weight.grid(row=5,column=3)
    self.Sets=tk.Label(self,text="Sets")
    self.Sets.grid(row=5,column=4)
    self.Reps=tk.Label(self,text="Reps")
    self.Reps.grid(row=5,column=5)
    self.label4=tk.Label(self, text="Exercise 1")
    self.label4.grid(row=7,column=1)
    self.entry1=tk.Entry(self)
    self.entry1.grid(row=7,column=2)
    self.Weight1=tk.Entry(self)
    self.Weight1.grid(row=7,column=3)
    self.Sets1=tk.Entry(self)
    self.Sets1.grid(row=7,column=4)
    self.Reps1=tk.Entry(self)
    self.Reps1.grid(row=7,column=5)
def Commit(self):
    Weight=int(self.Weight1.get())
    Sets=int(self.Sets1.get())
    Reps=int(self.Reps1.get())
    Volume=(Weight*Sets*Reps)
    print(Weight, Sets, Reps, Volume)
root=tk.Tk()
app=Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

What I'd like to have is another button that will populate the next row with identical labels and entries allowing the user to customize how many exercises they are entering.

Following on from that, I'll then need a way to call these new entries for the .get() function.
What isn't ideal is: a) hard coding the quantity of entry fields b) having only one entry field

The idea is that the user can enter as many exercises as they want, use the "commit" button and it will sent it to a mySQL database.

Any other additional feedback is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you try a button with a ref to self than can fill a list of label ? No tkinter since month, so maybe this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

In my example I create all common GUI elements in the method`create_top()`.

To keep track of the exercise number = grid row I created the variable `self.exercise_number`. Then I create each row of entrys in `create_widgets()`.

Since I don't need to access these widgets after commit is pressed I re-use the references to each widget.

Each row it processed by `Commit()` when I press the commit button.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, x=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master
        self.pack(padx=10, pady=10) # Added padding
        self.exercise_number = 0    # Keeping track of grid row
        self.create_top()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_top(self):
        # Create common GUI elements
        tk.Label(self, text="Athlete").grid(row=2)
        self.Athlete = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Athlete.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Commit')
        self.button1['command'] = self.Commit
        self.button1.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
        tk.Label(self,text="Program").grid(row=4, column=5)
        tk.Label(self,text="Exercise").grid(row=5, column=2)
        tk.Label(self,text="Weight").grid(row=5, column=3)
        tk.Label(self,text="Sets").grid(row=5, column=4)
        tk.Label(self,text="Reps").grid(row=5, column=5)

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Create new line of input fields
        self.exercise_number += 1
        row = 6 + self.exercise_number  # Calculate where to grid entrys
        self.label4 = tk.Label(self, text=f"Exercise {self.exercise_number}")
        self.label4.grid(row=row, column=1)
        self.Exercise = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Exercise.grid(row=row, column=2)
        self.Weight = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Weight.grid(row=row, column=3)
        self.Sets = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Sets.grid(row=row, column=4)
        self.Reps = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Reps.grid(row=row, column=5)

    def Commit(self):
        Weight = int(self.Weight.get())
        Sets = int(self.Sets.get())
        Reps = int(self.Reps.get())
        Volume = (Weight*Sets*Reps)
        print(Weight, Sets, Reps, Volume)
        self.create_widgets()   # Add new row

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```